# Is there classic mode in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: unity, 12.10

My computer is older (it has a Radeon 9200 video card) and it just doesn't seem to be able to handle Unity. Is there some way that I can set for the desktop to start up in classic mode instead? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to run this command:

```bash
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

Log out and you can see the classic gnome on the menu:

[image]

Comment: Let me try this out.. will get back to you :)

Comment: You are awesome, totally installed Classic GNOME :)

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

brings some additional software that may be useful, and looks prettier

Comment: Gnome panel is now installed with the gnome-session-fallback so there is no need to also do the gnome-panel.